# Container with optimized find like std::map but non associative

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a big `std::vector<int>` where I have to get an iterator so that I can call other functions of it, like `erase`. Looping through the vector to find the element I'm searching for takes a lot of time.

`std::map::find()` is much faster, but I don't want to allocate memory for the second value which I'm never going to use.

Is there any single-value container with `find()` or anything that gives me an iterator with similar speed as `std::map::find` ? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::unordered_map` or use the same `std::vector` that keeps an order of elements that you could apply standard algorithms for sorted containers as for example `std::equal_range`.